# displaying different data (info, numbers) into different tableview cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have tableview cells, each cell when tapped brings on screen calculator (SECOND viewcontroller), and when something is calculated i get numbers. I want for each cell to remember each calculated number,  i know i must use delegate to pass that numbers into previous tableviewcontroller into cell, problem is that all cells will get first number calculated. And when i click back tableview cells will not remember sum – numbers. So what the “simple” best path to do that, somehow to store data so each cell can remember specific numbers when i click back and forward. Here’s the video where i got stuck.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhQxdUnvk5g

Comment: It sounds like you need to read about the MVC pattern (model-view-controller), learn how your table view controller fits into that pattern, and implement the model part.

Comment: How you have structured your datasource for table-view? Can you give me overview ?

Comment: i will make new datasource class, connect everything and app will work, thx for helping rob and pratik